# hasAuthoritiy() work on one place but not on another....Spring Security problem

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/worker/login/").permitAll()
            .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/item/").hasAuthority("USER")
            .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/worker/getUserDetails/").hasAuthority("USER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and().cors();


    http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

It works for path "/worker/getUserDetails/", it works only if user is logged. But after logging path "/item/ is always 403(forbidden). Here is my controller for getUserDetails:

```
 @GetMapping("/getUserDetails")
public ResponseEntity<Worker> getUsername(@RequestHeader(value="Authorization") String jwtHeader){
    String username=jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwtHeader.substring(7));

    return ResponseEntity.ok(workerService.findByUsername(username));

}
```

And also controller for /item/ path:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public ResponseEntity<List<Item>> getAllItems(){
    return new ResponseEntity<>(itemService.noSale(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And MyUserDetials where i set actual role:

```
 @Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(worker.getRole()));
}
```

Edit: Here is what security logs say`2021-10-19 13:26:17.450 DEBUG 7288 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /item/noSale/] with attributes [hasAuthority('USER')] 2021-10-19 13:26:17.451 DEBUG 7288 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access 2021-10-19 13:26:17.453 DEBUG 7288 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request 2021-10-19 13:26:17.460 DEBUG 7288 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error`

On postman it is working, only on react side it doesn't work, so problem is with cors probably

```
 @Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return new CorsFilter(source);

}
```

Comment: And when you enable debug logs they tell you?

Comment: Looks like your matcher isn't using wildcards, e.g. `/item/*`. Also, I would highly recommend using the built-in [resource server support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/servlet/oauth2/oauth2-resourceserver.html) instead of a custom JWT filter.